# Kubernetes doesn't pull from private Docker Registry

Tags: docker, registry, private, kubernetes

I've deployed a private registry and can pull from it with docker pull x.x.x/name. The thing is that I can't make Kubernetes pull from that repository. I think I've followed all the answers on other topics, but they don't seem to do the trick.

.yaml file:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: private-image-test-1
spec:
  containers:
    - name: uses-private-image
      image: x.x.x/nginx_1
      imagePullPolicy: Always
      command: [ "echo", "SUCCESS" ]
  imagePullSecrets:
   - name: registrypullsecret
```

kubectl get pods:

```
NAME                   READY     STATUS                                                                 RESTARTS   AGE
private-image-test-1   0/1       Image: x.x.x/nginx_1 is ready, container is creating   0          4m
```

kubectl describe pods private-image-test-1

```
Name:           private-image-test-1
Namespace:      default
Node:           37.72.163.69/37.72.163.69
Start Time:     Fri, 06 May 2016 08:04:45 +0000
Labels:         <none>
Status:         Pending
IP:
Controllers:    <none>
Containers:
  uses-private-image:
    Container ID:
    Image:              x.x.x/nginx_1
    Image ID:
    Port:
    Command:
      echo
      SUCCESS
    QoS Tier:
      cpu:              BestEffort
      memory:           BestEffort
    State:              Waiting
      Reason:           Image: x.x.x/nginx_1 is ready, container is creating
    Ready:              False
    Restart Count:      0
    Environment Variables:
Conditions:
  Type          Status
  Ready         False 
Volumes:
  default-token-zrn4n:
    Type:       Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName: default-token-zrn4n
Events:
  FirstSeen     LastSeen        Count   From                    SubobjectPath                           Type            Reason        Message
  ---------     --------        -----   ----                    -------------                           --------        ------        -------
  4m            4m              1       {scheduler }                                                                    scheduled     Successfully assigned private-image-test-1 to 37.72.163.69
  4m            8s              30      {kubelet 37.72.163.69}  implicitly required container POD                       pulled        Successfully pulled image "gcr.io/google_containers/pause:0.8.0"
  4m            8s              30      {kubelet 37.72.163.69}  implicitly required container POD                       failed        Failed to create docker container with error: no such image
  4m            8s              30      {kubelet 37.72.163.69}                                                          failedSync    Error syncing pod, skipping: no such image
```

Any help is welcome at this point, thanks!

Comment: If you exec in, can you ping the docker registry? (you may need to use docker.io to deploy)  Alternatively, if you ssh into the box, can you hit the registry?

Comment: You forgot to describe the secret used to pull your images ("registrypullsecret"). Is it present? Does it have a valid syntax?

Comment: have you had it working ?

Answer (score 0):

In most cases where I've come across this issue, it is almost always your credential secret being incorrect. The proper format should be along the lines of

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: registrypullsecret
data:
  .dockerconfigjson: {BASE64 encoding of your config}
type: kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson
```

From memory, the `type` field has changed in recent versions of k8s so definitely check that you have the correct type listed.

Also, your yaml example has bad indenting, but thats likely a SO editor issue.

Comment: I added this and no change or whatsoever